# How create colorful(some days) calendar(PopupContent) in javafx?

Tags: java, javafx, calendar

I try to made calendar with using javafx. In particular calendar which show 1 month or 12 month, but user need option to change year. And some dates every year(for example 1 march and 3-25 october will be yellow color). But in JavaFx i found just popupContent. Which small(whatever i change width or height) and not customizing. Pls help me, i need your advice. And thank you for watching this topic).

Controller.java

```
public void initialize() {
        DatePickerSkin datePickerSkin = new DatePickerSkin(new DatePicker(LocalDate.now()));
        Pane popupContent = (Pane) datePickerSkin.getPopupContent();
        //popupContent.setPrefHeight(tab3.getPrefHeight());
        popupContent.setPrefWidth(tab3.getPrefWidth());
        tab3.getChildren().setAll(popupContent);
    }
```

Main.fxml

```
<AnchorPane fx:id="tab3" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="485.0" prefWidth="1200.0" stylesheets="@DarkStyle.css">
                            <children>
                                <DatePicker fx:id="calendar" layoutX="175.0" minHeight="400.0" minWidth="900.0" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="900.0" />
                                <ImageView fitHeight="59.0" fitWidth="63.0" layoutX="1133.0" layoutY="420.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true">
                                    <image>
                                        <Image url="@icon.png" />
                                    </image>
                                </ImageView>
                        <Label layoutX="572.0" layoutY="432.0" prefHeight="17.0" prefWidth="120.0" text="ПУ -3 " />
                            </children></AnchorPane>
```

I want create something like this.[image]

But have that - [image]

Comment: https://github.com/SeynalKim/JavaFXCalendar